# Create Columns by rows in another columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset, that I need to create new columns in the CODE column.

```
         Date   CODE      CODE.1               Values
0         NaT  Date1   CODE XPTO  2020-09-08 00:00:00
1         NaT  Date2   CODE XPTO            09/10/201
2  2020-08-01    100   CODE XPTO                   99
3  2020-09-01    220   CODE XPTO                  218
4  2020-10-01    330   CODE XPTO                  327
5  2020-11-01    440   CODE XPTO                  436
6  2020-12-01     50   CODE XPTO                   45
7         NaT  Date1  CODE XPTO2  2020-09-08 00:00:00
8         NaT  Date2  CODE XPTO2                  NaN
9  2020-08-01    100  CODE XPTO2                   99
10 2020-09-01    220  CODE XPTO2                  218
11 2020-10-01    330  CODE XPTO2                  327
12 2020-11-01    440  CODE XPTO2                  436
13 2020-12-01     50  CODE XPTO2                   45
```

The expected result is, two new columns Date1 and Date2, and if Date2 is null, then the value is current date.

```
          Date  CODE   CODE.1   Values             Date1    Date2
0   01/08/2020  100 CODE XPTO   99      08/09/2020 00:00    09/10/201
1   01/09/2020  220 CODE XPTO   218     08/09/2020 00:00    09/10/201
2   01/10/2020  330 CODE XPTO   327     08/09/2020 00:00    09/10/201
3   01/11/2020  440 CODE XPTO   436     08/09/2020 00:00    09/10/201
4   01/12/2020  50  CODE XPTO   45      08/09/2020 00:00    09/10/201
5   01/08/2020  100 CODE XPTO2  99      08/09/2020 00:00    09/03/2021
6   01/09/2020  220 CODE XPTO2  218     08/09/2020 00:00    09/03/2021
7   01/10/2020  330 CODE XPTO2  327     08/09/2020 00:00    09/03/2021
8   01/11/2020  440 CODE XPTO2  436     08/09/2020 00:00    09/03/2021
9   01/12/2020  50  CODE XPTO2  45      08/09/2020 00:00    09/03/2021


enter code here
```

Comment: The condition for creating a new column is a bit ambiguous: is Date1 unique or different?

Comment: Date1 can be different, in this example is equal, but depends of CODE.1 because this is start date that has sales

Comment: My answer is based on the fact that I don't depend on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simplified a bit more, but it splits the original dataframe and combines it with a transformed dataframe for the date. The last step is to replace the NA with today's date.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import io

data = '''
        Date   CODE      CODE.1               Values
0         NaT  Date1   "CODE XPTO"  "2020-09-08 00:00:00"
1         NaT  Date2   "CODE XPTO"            09/10/201
2  2020-08-01    100   "CODE XPTO"                   99
3  2020-09-01    220   "CODE XPTO"                  218
4  2020-10-01    330   "CODE XPTO"                  327
5  2020-11-01    440   "CODE XPTO"                  436
6  2020-12-01     50   "CODE XPTO"                   45
7         NaT  Date1  "CODE XPTO2"  "2020-09-08 00:00:00"
8         NaT  Date2  "CODE XPTO2"                  NaN
9  2020-08-01    100  "CODE XPTO2"                   99
10 2020-09-01    220  "CODE XPTO2"                  218
11 2020-10-01    330  "CODE XPTO2"                  327
12 2020-11-01    440  "CODE XPTO2"                  436
13 2020-12-01     50  "CODE XPTO2"                   45
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
dfs = df[df['Date'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True)
dfn = df[df['Date'].isnull()]
dfd = pd.pivot(dfn, index='CODE.1', columns='CODE', values='Values')
dfs = dfs.merge(dfd, left_on='CODE.1', right_on=dfd.index, how='outer')
dfs['Date2'].fillna(datetime.date.today(), inplace=True)
dfs
        Date    CODE    CODE.1     Values   Date1                   Date2
0   2020-08-01  100     CODE XPTO   99      2020-09-08 00:00:00     09/10/201
1   2020-09-01  220     CODE XPTO   218     2020-09-08 00:00:00     09/10/201
2   2020-10-01  330     CODE XPTO   327     2020-09-08 00:00:00     09/10/201
3   2020-11-01  440     CODE XPTO   436     2020-09-08 00:00:00     09/10/201
4   2020-12-01  50      CODE XPTO   45      2020-09-08 00:00:00     09/10/201
5   2020-08-01  100     CODE XPTO2  99      2020-09-08 00:00:00     2021-03-10
6   2020-09-01  220     CODE XPTO2  218     2020-09-08 00:00:00     2021-03-10
7   2020-10-01  330     CODE XPTO2  327     2020-09-08 00:00:00     2021-03-10
8   2020-11-01  440     CODE XPTO2  436     2020-09-08 00:00:00     2021-03-10
9   2020-12-01  50      CODE XPTO2  45      2020-09-08 00:00:00     2021-03-10
```